# Исключение System.InvalidOperationException при попытке чтения из бд

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Всем доброго времени суток, изучаю mvc и при попытке чтения из бд получаю исключение

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model backing the 'UserContext' context
>   has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First
>   Migrations to update the database

Исключение вылетает в Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyLesson.Models.Role>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<p>
    @foreach (var b in Model)
    {
        <div class="item">
            <span class="id">

                @b.Id
</span>
            <span class="name">

                @b.Name
</span>
            <span class="Code">

                @b.Code
</span>

            </div>
    }
</p>
```

а именно тут `@foreach (var b in Model)`
Ниже приложу весь код: 
UserContext.cs:

```
namespace MyLesson.Models
{
    public class UserContext : DbContext
    {
        public UserContext() : base("WebConnectionString")
        { }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Role.cs:

```
 public class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

HomeController.cs:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        UserContext db = new UserContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Roles);
        }
    }
```

web.config :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.2\sql;Initial Catalog=Web;User ID=admin;Password=1234"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

База была уже создана и база не пустая. Помогите разобраться в чем проблема ? и с чем это связано ? спасибо большое

Comment: _Additional information: The model backing the 'UserContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database_ : _Дополнительная информация: Модель 'UserContext' была изменена с момента создания базы. Рассмотрите вопрос об использовании **Code First Migrations** для обновления базы_

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо разобрался